# ロードバランサを用いたWebサーバ複数台構成にNFSファイル共有を使用したが応答速度が遅い

Tags: linux, サーバー管理

さくらクラウドを利用しています。

元々はサーバー1台で稼働させていたのですが、ピーク時のスケールアウトのため、ロードバランサを用いて以下のような2台構成を試みたところ、1時間あたり5000PVを超えたあたりからWebサーバーの応答速度が非常に遅くなる(chromeのデベロッパーズツール->networkでTTFBが3秒以上)現象が発生し、その後PVの増加とともに応答速度の遅延時間が伸びていきました。

ただ、応答速度が遅くなるにもかかわらずサーバーA、サーバーBともCPU、メモリ、ロードアベレージ、DiskI/O等についてはサーバー監視ソフトのMuninで確認したところ、使用率が突出するといったことは見受けられませんでした。

追記：
当時のCPUのIO WaitとメモリのSWAPです。
[IO Wait(%)]サーバーA
・時間帯 4:50～5:50 特に動作に問題が無かった時間帯
Cur:2.93、Min:1.98、Avg:3.10、Max:4.39
・時間帯 6:25～7:25 応答が遅くなっていた時間帯
Cur:1.84、Min:1.81、Avg:3.17、Max:4.61

[IO Wait(%)]サーバーB
・時間帯 4:50～5:50 特に動作に問題が無かった時間帯
サーバーBはこの時間帯記録の取得に失敗しておりました
・時間帯 6:25～7:25 応答が遅くなっていた時間帯
Cur:7.64、Min:4.80、Avg:6.34、Max:8.00

[SWAP(GB)]こちらはサーバーA,B共に0.00
・時間帯 4:50～5:50 特に動作に問題が無かった時間帯
Cur:0.00、Min:0.00、Avg:0.00、Max:0.00
・時間帯 6:25～7:25 応答が遅くなっていた時間帯
Cur:0.00、Min:0.00、Avg:0.00、Max:0.00

設定や構成等を見直せば改善するのか、そもそもnfsによるスクリプト＆データの共有によるサーバー分散構成に無理があるのか、といった部分が判断できず質問させていただきました。

CentOS6.9でファイルシステムはext4を利用しています。
(以下IPアドレスはダミーです)

【さくらクラウド上のサーバースペック】
・サーバーA
CPU：20コア、メモリ：32GB
・サーバーB
CPU：16コア、メモリ：32GB
・ロードバランサ
　ハイスペックプラン、冗長化なし
　送信トラフィック: 1Gbps、受信トラフィック: 500Mbps、セッション数: 10,000、セッション、毎秒接続数: 3,000cps程度

【ディレクトリ共有に関する設定】
・サーバーA(IP=99.100.101.1)
Webサーバーとして稼働、またデータ(テキストファイルベース)とPHPスクリプトを格納。
/var/www/scripts/ ・・・自身の/var/www/scripts_src をnfsでmount
/var/www/scripts_src/ ・・・ここをnfsにより共有。PHPスクリプトとデータが格納されているディレクトリ
※自身のディレクトリをnfsでマウントしている理由は、PHPのflockをサーバー間で機能させる目的です。

・サーバーA側の/etc/exports設定
/var/www/scripts_src 99.100.101.*(rw,no_root_squash,async)

・サーバーB(IP=99.100.101.2)
Webサーバーとして稼働、データやPHPスクリプトはサーバーAのものを使用
/var/www/scripts/ ・・・サーバーAの/var/www/scripts_src をnfsでmount

・サーバーA、Bの/etc/fstabによるマウント設定
99.100.101.1:/var/www/scripts_src /var/www/scripts nfs rsize=32768,wsize=32768,hard,intr,async 0 0

【その他】
・なお上記構成前は、サーバーAの1台のみで稼働させており、50000pv/h程度でも問題なくさばけていたが、70000pv/h程度でCPUの頭打ちが出始めたため、上記複数台構成を検討しました。

他にも確認すべき点がございましたら、ご指摘いただければ幸いです。

【質問の修正履歴】
-Firewall Throughputとeth0 traffic、ロードバランサの「反映」に関する記述を見直しました
-2台構成以前でのサーバーの応答状況を追記しました。
-サーバーAが自身のディレクトリをNFSでマウントしている理由につき、追記しました。
-質問文の構成を見直しました。
-サーバー監視にMuninを使用している旨を追記
-CPUのIO wait とメモリのSWAP状況を追記

Comment: 文章を全体的に推敲してください。意味がわからない点が多すぎます。Firewall Throughputとはなんですか。「13K」「1k」とか単位はなんでしょうか。「80MB」は読んで字のごとく「80MB」なのか「80MB/sec」なのか「80Mbps」なのかどれでしょうか。上り下り区別付いてますか。「反映」とはなんでしょうか。これだけではないですので全体的に見直してください。

Comment: Firewall Throughputとeth0 trafficについては、サーバー監視ソフトのMuninで表示されるの内容を記載いたしました。Firewall Throughputは1秒間のパケット転送量、eth0 trafficはNICのパケットの転送量でOUTの値となります。

Comment: なお、ロードバランサの「反映」という表現ですが、さくらクラウド上のコントロールパネルでは、設定を変更したあと「反映」というボタンをクリックすることで設定内容が有効になるという仕様のため、「反映」を行うという表現とさせていただきました。

Comment: リソースの確認はMuninを使用されているようですが、プラグインを設定すればNFS(クライアント/サーバ)やhttpdの使用率も表示できるので、これらも合わせて確認してみては如何でしょうか。

Comment: そのようなプラグインもあるのですね。そちらも確認してみたいと思います。有用な情報をいただき、ありがとうございます。

Comment: NFSっぽいですけど、念のためSwap使用量とCPUのIO Waitの値が高いか見てもらえますか

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。CPUのIO WaitとメモリのSWAPを追記いたしました。サーバーB側のIO Waitが少し高いようです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**提案1**
応答速度の改善につながるかは分かりませんが、サーバAについては
自身をNFSマウントする設定は冗長な気がします。
(サーバBと設定を揃えるためあえてそうしてるのかもしれませんが)

ローカルのディレクトリをマウント、もしくはシンボリックリンクで
十分なのではないでしょうか。

**提案2**
NFS共有するデータを最小限に絞る = 共通に読み書きする**データ**のみNFSで参照し、
スクリプトは各マシンのローカルに置いてみる(必要時にrsync等で同期する)。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。提案１に関しまして、サーバAで自身のディレクトリをマウントしているのは、PHPからのflockを有効とするためにこのように設定いたしました。サーバーA自身がnfs経由でファイルにアクセスしないと、サーバーBとの間でPHPのflockが機能せず、サーバー間でのファイルロックを無視して書き込む現象が発生したためです。この点、解決する方法がございましたら、おっしゃる通りこのような冗長な設定は回避したいところですが．．．。

Comment: 提案２に関しまして、rsyncについては知らなかったので、こちら一度調査の上検討してみたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

NFSを使用するということは

- サーバーBの当該ファイルI/OがサーバーBのネットワークを経由してサーバーAのネットワークにも及ぶということ、つまりサーバーA・B双方のネットワークI/Oが増加する
- サーバーAとしてもローカルアクセスからネットワークアクセスに変更されるため、ファイル操作の一つ一つにオーバーヘッドがかかるようになる
- もちろんサーバーAはNFSサーバーとしての負荷もかかる

という影響がでるわけですが、この辺りはご認識の上での設計かと思います。

その上で環境に目を向けますと、5000PV/hourつまり2PV/sec程度の処理にCPU 20コア・メモリ 32GBを要してなお足りないとのこと。根拠のない個人的な感想ですが、PHPスクリプトの処理がここまで効率が悪いとざるで水をすくうようなものでハードウェアをいくら増強しても解決しないような気がします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。単一サーバーで稼働させている状況では、5000PV/hourでスペックが足りなくなることはありません。このアクセスは早朝の最低PVに近い状態のものです。最大ピークに達した際のスケールアウトを想定しての構成を検討しておりました。上記のロードバランサ＆NFS構成にした場合に、5000pv/hour程度でページの表示に問題が出始めた状態です。

Comment: なお、単一サーバーで稼働させていた状態では、50000pv/hourでも問題は発生せず、70000pv/hourあたりでCPUが頭打ちになり始める状況でした。

Comment: @Sugihey さん、質問者さんの心に応えているのではなく質問文に記載の内容に答えています。コメントで補足するのではなく質問文に記載してください。その際、suzukisさんも指摘されていますが推敲・校正してください。

Comment: さま 確かに質問文にも反映させるべきでした。まだわかりにくい文章とおっしゃられるかもしれませんが、質問文を修正いたしました。

Answer (score 0):

質問文は訂正済みですが、`eth0`の帯域使用量が80Mbpsと記載されていたので、サーバAとサーバB間の通信帯域が一杯のように予想します。(サーバ間の通信帯域は100Mbpsと(さくらクラウドのページからは)読み取りました)

＃1Gbpsなのは外部との通信帯域と読み取りました。

その場合、ネットワークサービスの追加契約等でサーバ間の通信帯域を広げるとよいかと思います。

＃理想的には、外部通信とは別のネットワークセグメントが設定でき、NFS通信はすべてそこを通せるとよいです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。なるほど、その点については考慮にいたっておりませんでした。さくらクラウドの仕様を再度確認の上、通信帯域の使用削減、帯域確保など検討致します。

Comment: 仮想スイッチ接続は最低500Mbps(サーバのメモリ量による)です。100Mbpsというのは共有セグメントにサーバを接続する場合のことを見誤っていませんか。https://manual.sakura.ad.jp/cloud/support/technical/network.html#support-network-01

Answer (score 0):

NFS経由での

- アクセスに伴うファイルやスクリプトの読み込み
- 書き込みの排他制御

のどちらかまたは両方がボトルネックになっている、というのが単純に考えられる理由です。

しかし、PHPでファイルを操作する程度のWebサーバにしてはサーバのスペックが異常に高く、これが必要とされるものだとすると処理の規模や内容がちょっと想像出来ません。一方で、システム構成やネットワーク構成や性能情報は極断片的なものなので、回答も場当たり的なものにしかなりません。ひょっとすると全然別のところの問題かも知れません。

場当たり的な解決策で仮に解決できたとしても、早晩次のトラブル(ありがちなのはデッドロックかファイル破損)に見舞われるでしょう。

データの共有にはRDBMSを使う一般的なシステム構成に見直されることをお勧めします。